# Is JSON better than XML? Which one is more secured?

Tags: android, json, xml, web-services, rest

I'm very much clear about using JSON and XML, but still while comparing each other I cant find differences related to security. Which one is more secure? Which one I should choose?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627284/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-xml

Comment: Why should there be any difference in security? You just structure your data differently.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862310/json-and-xml-comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In compare to `JSON` and `XML` , there is no difference in security but `JSON` is much faster than `XML` thats why we prefer JSOn over XMl...But if you see from security point of view than you can go for `SOAP`

Comment: How is XML more secure?  Could you please elaborate?  Of all the answers to this question, only yours makes this claim.

Comment: no difference see the update

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, it's as if I wrote this answer in French -- equally valid, just need to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

No difference both were made to make data transfer easy over the network, both are platform indepedent, language independent.  It is the way you code makes them secure or insecure.