# Unable to fetch data from json file using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-applications

Currently I am working on the project where i have to fetch information from web API into web application using JQuery.

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:52227/api/Values",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("hello");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

When I run this application it is not showing me any output.

Comment: if you put this url into your browser ```"http://localhost:52227/api/Values``` what does the screen show?

Comment: i am getting the xml format of my web api                 <User>
<Id>2</Id>
<Password>pass</Password>
<UserName>user</UserName>
</User>

Comment: ok, so it is xml, not json

Comment: yess i am getting output as a xml

Comment: change your dataType to ```dataType:"xml"``` and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided is syntactically correct. The get request is most likely failing and you haven't provided an error function for the request. You can add an error callback like this

```
$.ajax
(
{
    url: "http://localhost:52227/api/Values",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("hello");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("test");
    }
}
)
```

Here is a JSFiddle showing it in action.

http://jsfiddle.net/1mqotn6v/2/

Comment: but here i am getting error ( i am getting test in my alert box) : what is the error in this code ???

Comment: You can console.log the return object to glean some information about the error or you can open the developer tools in your browser and look at the network tab for some information about the error. I have updated the jsfiddle with the console.log instead of the alert: http://jsfiddle.net/1mqotn6v/7/

Comment: is the issue not that he is telling jquery to expect JSON, when in fact xml is being returned?

Comment: That's most likely the underlying issue but the above answer will let him know how to troubleshoot these errors in the future

Comment: I am getting the error as--  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:52227/api/Values. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access -- and when i run my code success :function(data){ alert(data.UserName) ;} ( where user name is my property ) it is giving me message as "undefined"

Comment: absolutely, but he should be aware that xml and json are two different things http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620270/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-xml